# Page redirection in ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a project in written in ASP.NET MVC and I am struggling with this error for a few days now. Below is the scenario.

**SCENARIO**: This project uses **T4MVC plugin** by the way

1. User logs in
2. After successful login the user **should be redirected to the Index.cshtml** where there are other links that can be navigated to when clicked.
3. Now, the problem is, after successful login the user is automatically redirected to another page instead of the Index.cshtml page (this happens without clicking any links from the Index.cshtml)

Any ideas what's happening here?

**UPDATE:**

Code for the login. This is for the login form posting. It redirects to /Administration controller with an Index() action method.

```
    public virtual ActionResult Index(LoginFormInput loginFormInput, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        if (!FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(loginFormInput.Username, loginFormInput.Password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("login", BridgeDirect.Properties.Common.LoginFailure);
            return this.View();
        }

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginFormInput.Username, loginFormInput.RememberMe);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction(MVC.Login.Index());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your login POST method ?

Comment: We can't really help if you don't show us what you've done or you're doing

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: the first two `ifs` returns the same `View` the user is on that is the `Login`. the last `if else` should return to the previous Url `returnUrl` or the `Index`

Answer (score 1):

In method of controller where you validate the user
If success just return RedirectToAction("Index","Controller")

Comment: Tried this but same thing happens. It proceeds to another page after hitting the Index() action method in AdministrationController.cs

Answer (score 1):

Magic happens in the Account Controller (i guess you are using ASP.NET individual user accounts)

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
          // AFTER A SUCCESSFULL LOGIN THIS REDIRECTS THE USER TO THE 
          // PREVIOUS PAGE
            case SignInStatus.Success: 
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You still redicrect him to the return url after a successfull login, you just need to modify that to your desires.

Comment: Yes, it redirects to the return url which is /Administration but the problem is it doesn't redirect to the Index() method instead it redirects to other methods.

Comment: And what route is registered in your routeconfig.cs file if there is any?

Comment: Then just replace the redirect returnUrl with return RedirectToAction("Index","Administration");

Comment: Tried that, same thing happens. It hits Index() but presents another page.

Comment: Can you show us your RouteConfig.cs ? It should be in the App_Start

Comment: This is the route:

routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Administration",
               url: "Administration/{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Administration", action = "Index" });

Comment: Show us the index action(s) of Admin controller aswell please

Comment: It just simply returns the view.

public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
return this.RedirectToAction(MVC.Login.Index());
```

To this

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","TheIndexMethodController");
```

Which if I'm guessing will be some HomeController, so like below:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```